# How do I use a previously written function within another function in Python?

Tags: python

I'm using the Python coding program called Wing IDE.

I created a function that generates a list of n random numbers where the numbers we between 0 and 10. I'm now trying to write a function that will calculate the average of a list of numbers.

I want to use my previous function (named `randomNumbers(n)`) inside my new function, but I don't know how to call the function and run it within my new function.

Can anyone help?

For example I have my new function `calculateAverage(n)` and I'm trying to run `randomNumbers(n)` within `calculateAverage(n)` and then find the average of the list of numbers that `randomNumbers(n)`creates.

Comment: So why is this downvoted? Duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

Well calling a function has the syntax `functionName(arg1, arg2, ...)`.

```
def calculate_average(n):
    # call the function and store the result.
    random_list = randomNumbers(n)

    average = 0
    # iterate through random_list, add each number to average

    return average / n
```

Or more cleanly

```
 def calculate_average(n):
     random_sum = sum(randomNumbers(n))
     # now you have the sum of the list of numbers,
     # getting the average is simple
```

Comment: `average = 0; return average/n` in what case would that NOT return zero (ignoring of course the case of `0/0`)?

Comment: @Josh Well did you read the comment directly below `average = 0`? It's obviously homework so I omitted part so of the logic

Comment: @Josh "iterate through random_list adding each number to average"

Comment: I realized that immediately after posting my comment. Sorry about that. +1, I thought I had a good grasp on your code so I didn't bother with the comments. Though naming the variable `average` and then using it in the formula to find the average is a little confusing (from a readability standpoint)